# How to subtract date from an expression

Tags: c#, linq

In an expression I want to remove 6 days from it.

```
priceData.EffectiveStartDate= Data.PeriodData;
```

and from below expression(mark as **).

```
var newData = data.Select(a => new IHSData
  {
     PriceSymbol = Convert.ToString(a.PriceId),
     **PeriodData = Convert.ToDateTime(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.Period).FirstOrDefault()),**
     StatusID = Convert.ToInt32(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.StatusId).FirstOrDefault()),
      Price = Convert.ToDouble(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.price).FirstOrDefault()),
      PriceType = MasterData.Where(x => x.Code == a.PriceId.ToString()).Select(s => s.IHSType).FirstOrDefault()
   });
```

If I am doing -6 from expression or  `DateTime date = Date.AddDays(-6).Date;`

Its not working. thanks

Comment: What have you tried. Have you looked at the documentation? (`AddDays`)

Comment: @GiladGreen Days.Add I saw, but Days.Subtract didn't.. something wrong in the documentation :p

Comment: You say not working. What does it mean? Exception? unexpected data?

Comment: *"Its not working"* Woah, you don't have to be **that** specific, you are overwhelming us with details here!

Comment: Who is down voting my question

Answer (score 2):

There is method in `DateTime` called `AddDays()`, that returns a new `DateTime` that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance. And if you pass as parameter negative number it will subtract days from it:

```
PeriodData = Convert.ToDateTime(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.Period).FirstOrDefault()).AddDays(-6),
```

MSDN link -> [DateTime.AddDays Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Who's downvoting and why?